# Handle Large Data for Conversion of Hex Data

Tags: excel, hex, notepad++, vba

I have a Text/CSV File of more than 10,000,000 Rows and 3 Columns.
Columns Names: ClientName, CLientMobile, ClientData

ClientData is in Hex format.

**Presently I am doing:**

1. Splitting the File in multiple parts of 900,000 rows each
2. Opening Each File - Say File 1
3. Pasting the below stated Function as Macro (Macro for Hex2Text)

---

```
Public Function HexToText(Text As Range) As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim DummyStr As String
  For i = 1 To Len(Text) Step 2
    DummyStr = DummyStr & Chr(Val("&H" & (Mid(Text, i, 2))))
    DoEvents
    Next i
  HexToText = DummyStr
End Function
```

---

4. Converting Each Hex Value on Column "ClientData" in Readable Text by using above Function `"Hex2Text"`
5. Saving the Sheet.

**Issues Faced:**

1. I have to split all such big files in 900,000 row limit due to Excel limitations
2. It takes lot of time for calculations to run when I copy past formulae for Hex2Text for all 900,000 rows for Hex Values conversion in "ClientData"

**Solution Desired:**

1. Is there any other software that I can use for the same purpose to avoid spitting and avoid huge time wasted in Excel calculations for Hext2Text conversion.

Any simple solution/idea's will be welcome.

Comment: 10M lines in a text file? Why don't you use a database?

Comment: frankly dont know how to.

Comment: This is a simple task for a programming or a scripting language such as Perl or Python.